# iOS \ Android Facebook SDK - get friends list, some without username

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using iOS and Android Facebook native SDK in my app.
In general, I'm getting the friends list, each with name, birthday (if public) and username.
About the birthday property, I know that one can block it from appearing in mobile apps (or at all). But I see that in some rare cases, username is NULL. I couldn't find any explanation for it in the Facebook documentation.

Any help will be great.

Comment: HI, have you tried to get your friend list using the graph explorer ?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: @Ali Yes, it was also null.

Answer (score 0):

Some people just haven't chosen a username.

If you look on the www page, their profile links will be facebook.com/profile.php?id=user_id rather than facebook.com/username.

Comment: So if I want to send this kind of user email, through the Facebook email (e.g: myUserName@facebook.com) - is there anything I can do about it?